# Rails - session value not set after redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, redirect

I'm setting a session variable and then doing a redirect:

Controller #1:

```
 session[:session_id] = data['session_id']
 puts "-------from session id is: #{session[:session_id]}"
 redirect_to(:controller => :company_setup, :action => :index) and return
```

I can see that the session id get set properly. However, when I get into the company_setup controller, session_id is some other value...

Any idea what's going on here? Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

OK.. I think I've done this before - I think the problem is that 'session_id' - is reserved by rails.

Solution: use a different session variable e.g. session[:user_session_id]

Comment: can you try it with a different name?

Comment: @reto - yes that's what I ended up doing - sorry, I'll amend the answer to be more clear that that's what I did to fix it